# Почему return ''outside function'' и где он должен быть?

Tags: python

Данный код является доказательством "парадокса о днях рождения"

```
def birthday(amount, iteration=10000):
    from random import randrange

matches=0
for x in range(iteration):

    birthdays = []

    for y in range (1,amount+1):
        birthdays.append(randrange(1,366))

    tmp = set(birthdays)

    if len(tmp) != len(birthdays):
        matches+=1

return matches/iteration * 100


result=birthday(23)
print(result)
```

Comment: потому что отступы?

Comment: я сделал табуляцию, все равно пишет return outside function...

Answer (score 2):

У вас вообще беда с пробелами из-за этого Ваша функция `birthday()` принимает на вход `amount` и `iteration`, не возвращает ничего, а только импортирует `from random import randrange`. Если Вы хотите, чтобы весь код, кроме вывода результата, был в теле функции это должно выглядеть так:

```
def birthday(amount, iteration=10000):
    from random import randrange

    matches = 0
    for x in range(iteration):
        birthdays = []

        for y in range(1, amount + 1):
            birthdays.append(randrange(1, 366))

        tmp = set(birthdays)

        if len(tmp) != len(birthdays):
            matches += 1

    return matches / iteration * 100


result = birthday(23)
print(result)
```

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, как правильный)